# Jquery script doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

I'm newbie with jQuery and I my facing the following problem.

I'm trying to use a mask, but the script doesn't work. At all.

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
            $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
            $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
            $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="date">
    <input type="text" id="phone">
    <input type="text" id="tin">
    <input type="text" id="ssn">

</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong?

I'm using the plugin from this site: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Are you sure you placed the files correctly? It works here http://jsfiddle.net/95uu0f2s/

Comment: it is strange. but it doesnt work.

Comment: I've copied the content of plugin script to a new file, and saved to the folder that called js. But isnt working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the code. And  I used [this latest jQuery Mask Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/). It works. 
[Here are some examples , they might help.](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Only change I did is

```
<script src="jquery.mask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You may have put your files in wrong location.
You can check those using the built in `inspect element` functionality (right click and you can see it) in Google chrome. If the console indicate missing .js files you can correct them. 
There are ways for other browser to check those also.

Comment: @Hellon Canella Machado : If you solved your problem, Please update the question or place a comment here ,indicating how you did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maskedinput.js either not be found or there is something wrong in this script

change from

```
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```